# Fixing a broken btrfs partition?

Tags: opensuse, btrfs, gparted

I'm having a lot of trouble with an install of openSUSE Leap (14.2) on a btrfs partition. Today I booted the computer up and it would get stuck at the loading screen, without ever getting to the actual login. I then booted it up in recovery mode, and the result was it stayed for a long time stuck on a startjob on sysroot (4 minutes and some), then still didn't boot, but gave me the option to login as root and use btrfs to fix things. The broken partition is `/dev/sda6`, namely, my root partition. Home partition is separated. I tried running `btrfs check` on it but it said it didn't exist. I tried rebooting from an openSUSE install USB stick and upgrading the system; it didn't even recognise there was a Linux install at all. I tried rebooting from a Gecko live USB stick and am running Gparted to check the partition, and the result is that it looks stuck and frozen at the "check file system on /dev/sda6 for errors and (if possible) fix them" step.

Are there any other things I could try before simply nuking the partition with extreme prejudice and reinstalling from scratch?

Comment: Check `dmesg` for anything related to the sda6.